# Why does Nexus 4 go through resume/suspend cycles periodically while the phone is put to sleep?

Tags: android, kernel, resume, suspend

I found an interesting behaviour of the suspend/resume process of nexus 4. When I press the power button to suspend the phone and leave it there for some time, the phone would automatically resume, then suspend, then resume and suspend again ... The longer I leave it there, the more resume/suspend cycles it will go through as if there are some events that are waking up the phone periodically.

I found this behaviour by setting the CONFIG_PM_DEBUG kernel flag to "y" and looking at the kernel log (cat /proc/kmsg).

The screen is always off during this entire time until I press the power button again.

Does anyone know why it does that?

Thanks

Comment: Could be either network tickles or timers from the phone side in either platform code or app/service code.

Comment: hmmm... Wifi is turned off all the time. Timers, maybe. could it be the RTC (real time clock?)